# How to use setter in python constructor

Tags: python, oop

the python gurus, i got this task i was given to complete, i have ended up writing the code, but i keep getting this error `"Oops! Don't forget to use the setters in your constructor, and print "<attribute name> changed" whenever a setter is called (regardless of whether the correct type was supplied)"` my code has one constructor and six methods. the first three methods are getters while the last three are setters. My problem is how do i resolve this error `Oops! Don't forget to use the setters in your constructor, and print "<attribute name> changed" whenever a setter is called (regardless of whether the correct type was supplied)` Because it seems am using the setters already but don't know why this error persist thanks. Here is my full code:

```
class TodoItem:
    def __init__(self, title, description, completed=False):
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.completed = completed

    def getTitle(self):     
        print ("title accessed")
        return self.title

    def getDescription(self):      
        print ("description accessed")
        return self.description

    def getCompleted(self):       
        print ("completed accessed")
        return self.completed

    def setTitle(self, newtitle):
        print ("title changed")
        if type(newtitle) == str:
            self.title = newtitle
        else:
            print ("invalid value title changed")
            self.title = None

    def setDescription(self, newdescription):
        print ("description changed")
        if type(newdescription) == str:
            self.description = newdescription
        else:
            print ("invalid value description changed")
            self.description = None

    def setCompleted(self, newbool):
        print ("completed changed")
        if type(newbool) == bool:
            self.completed = newbool
        else:
            print ("invalid value completed changed")
            self.completed = None
```

This is my code to test the code above:

```
mytodo = TodoItem(99,"make a list and go to the store")
mytodo.setTitle(99)
print (mytodo.getTitle())
```

Comment: Maybe you should be using `property` instead of Java-like getter / setters.

Comment: This is no built in Python error. It is thrown by some custom code. I guess you got to use the setter methods like this `self.setTitle(title)` instead of `self.title = title` in your constructor.

Comment: Regardless of whether you are supposed to be using properties, your "constructor" `__init__` is *not* using your `setXXX` methods.

Comment: This is presumably a homework assignment with an automatic grading system. You should however know that you are being taught Python wrong; it is *unidiomatic* to write getters and setters in Python.  (And even if you did, you should use Python `lower_case_with_underscore` naming styles.) It seems that your teacher wants to write Java rather than Python.

Comment: That said, the instructions seem clear; it wants you to use the setters in your `__init__` method, and you aren't.

Comment: How do i do that then @Daniel Roseman

Comment: I don't understand your question. You know how to do this, you are already doing it in the second snippet.

Comment: But the code is still not passing through.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in python we don't use getter and setter, anyway, if you really need them there is two good ways to do it (illustrates with var1 and var2):

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.__var1 = var1
        self.__var2 = var2

    @property
    def var1(self):
        return self.__var1

    @var1.setter
    def var1(self, value):
        self.__var1 = value

    def get_var2(self):
        return self.__var2

    def set_var2(self, value):
        self.__var2 = value

    var2 = property(get_var2, set_var2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # With those implementations you can call the getter and setter as if
    # you directly call and modify the variable (which is what we want in
    # python).
    e = Example()

    e.var1 = 1 # will call the method with the @var1.setter decorator
    print(e.var1) # will call the method with the @property decorator

    e.var2 = 1 # will call the method set_var2()
    print(e.var2) # will call the method get_var2()
```

Also, in python to indicate that variable are private we add "__" before them and "_" means protected.

Comment: if user uses a constructor like  e = Example(1,1)  , getter and setter is useless, so it is recommended if you going to use setter and getter make your constructor empty